# Restrict creation of Sessions which do not have principal

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, spring-session

I am using Spring sessions with JDBC and it works fine. But there are numerous sessions being created without principal.
Even a simple curl request creates a new session entry in the database.

**Can we restrict session creation for sessions without a principal?**

Principal here refers to the logged in user.

**Sample DB Data:**

```
SESSION_ID| CREATION_TIME| LAST_ACCESS_TIME | MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL | PRINCIPAL_NAME

| 0112a88c | 1567062697443 | 1567062697443 | 43200 | abc@gmail.com

| 0123f31e | 1567063051563 | 1567063051563 | 43200 | NULL
```

UPDATE: These sessions were created for status api calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the SessionCreationPolicy does not work. I solved this by introducing a filter.

```html
@Component
public class ExcludeSessionRepositoryFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse,
                                  FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    httpRequest.setAttribute("org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.FILTERED", Boolean.TRUE);
    filterChain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
  }
}
```

I will exclude session creation for custom apis using the following code. This will not create dummy sessions in the SPRING_SESSION table.

```html
@Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean sessionExclusionFilterRegBean(ExcludeSessionRepositoryFilter excludeSessionRepositoryFilter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(excludeSessionRepositoryFilter);

    registrationBean.setOrder(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/hello", "/status");

    return registrationBean;
  }
```